# Append encoded URL to existing

Tags: php, html, pocket

I'm trying to create a function to turn a link into a link to 'add link to Pocket' via getpocket.com/save.

I don't want to use the API and have users have to start logging in to their Pocket account - the /save link works if they're already logged in on the current browser.

I have:

```
function save_pocket($url){
    $enc = rawurlencode($url);
    $pocket = "http://getpocket.com/save/?url=";
    return $pocket.$enc;
}
```

`save_pocket()` is then called in `<a href="`.

But this returns either `$url` or `$enc`, I can't tell which. But the issue is it's not adding `$pocket` prefix.

Why?

Comment: Where do you call `save_pocket`?

Comment: There is something borked somewhere else. As always in such situations: dump the intermediate result, so `$pocket.$enc` into a log file and check what it contains. Every other approach is just poking around in the mist.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - href.

Comment: @arkascha - sorry, I'm a bit new, can you elaborate on how?

Comment: are you sure you are calling it like this `echo "<a href='".save_pocket("yoursite.com")."'>Click</a>";` ?

Comment: Just insert something like `syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "final url: ---$pocket.$enc---");` right before the return statement and make sure you have error loggin turned on in your php setup. Then monitor the log file using `tail -f /path/to/logfile` or similar and spot the output.

Comment: @ionutvmi Thanks, but with that I get `$url` echoed on screen, and the link is only to `$pocket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, in the end **it boiled down to me just being an idiot**.

I was using a function which `echo`'d the url to pass urls into my function.

Swapped that for one that just presents url as a string, and it works like a champ.

*Thanks again for tolerating my idiocy...*